# Recursive searching through directories structure

Tags: python-3.x

I created recursive function for finding directory with `ID` I need to use:

```
def find_id(content, id):
    for drive_obj in content:
        print('Got {}'.format(drive_obj.id))
        if drive_obj.id == id:
            print('Find id in {}'.format(drive_obj.id))
            return drive_obj
        elif type(drive_obj) == Directory and drive_obj.children:
            print('{} has children'.format(drive_obj.id))
            return find_id(drive_obj.children, id)
```

After running test(`find_id(example_structure, 'c')`) on this directories structure:

```
dir_a
-----dir_b
----------file_e
-----dir_c
-----dir_d
dir_f

Logs:
    Got a
    a has children
    Got b
    b has children
    Got e
```

i got a problem, because function after finding file with `id = e` doesn't examine next `dir_c`. It just return `None` instead of continue the loop. Something wrong with my function or my understanding of it/recursive functions at all?

Comment: have you tried `os.walk()` ?

Comment: There is a dictionary with Directory objects i got from Google Drive. And for filesystems I prefer to use `pathlib` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you `return find_id(drive_obj.children, id)` even if you don't find the directory you're looking for:

```
def find_id(content, id):
    for drive_obj in content:
        print('Got {}'.format(drive_obj.id))
        if drive_obj.id == id:
            print('Find id in {}'.format(drive_obj.id))
            return drive_obj
        elif type(drive_obj) == Directory and drive_obj.children:
            print('{} has children'.format(drive_obj.id))
            result = find_id(drive_obj.children, id)  # Now if find_id returns None, we don't stop
            if result:  # result is not None if your objects can be falsy
                return result
```

You want `find_id` to return `None` if it doesn't find anything, and you want to avoid bubbling those `None` results up to the caller.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Too much time was wasted on such a stupid mistake.